# What are bionic and libhybris?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-for-android

In reading about Ubuntu Touch and Ubuntu for Android, I have noticed references to "bionic" and "libhybris" that are made fairly often.

I assume that libhybris is a library because of the "lib" prefix, but that's about all I know.

What are bionic and libhybris, and what do they do?

Edit: @maggotbrain asked if I could link to some of the sources where I found mention of bionic/libhybris.  Here is a comment [on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5318613), and [here is another](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4999070).  Those are the only ones that I could find, what really got me wondering was when someone mentioned it at an [Ubuntu LoCo meeting](http://loco.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: I went through all the trouble of typing libhybris info google and wlicked the 2nd link... [phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE5Mjk) EDIT: (to be more complete for those who are unable to google)
So, introducing libhybris, http://github.com/stskeeps/libhybris - Hybris is a solution that commits hybris, by allowing us to use bionic-based HW adaptations in glibc systems. Practically, if you know what libdl is, this is a libdl-API-like implementation that happens to be able to load Android libraries, and overrides some symbols from bionic with glibc based ones. The ap

Comment: Could you perhaps link to some of the articles that you are referring to, so we have a better context for your question?

Comment: @ScottGoodgame what are you talking about?  I saw the Phoronix article *before* I posted the question.  The Phoronix editors often assume that their audience knows a fair bit about Linux (which is justifiable, as they are mainly targeting skilled Linux users).  *This has nothing to do with Google or finding the information*, and everything to do with getting a relatively easy to understand translation of the content.  The majority of the articles that mention bionic and libhybris are going to be geared towards those who have their hands in the guts of the kernel.  Stop assuming that I am lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bionic, according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_%28software%29):

> The Bionic libc is a derivation of the BSD standard C library code that was originally developed by Google for the Android embedded operating system

If you are wondering what the C standard library is, it's a library that all applications written in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) use. It contains input and output functions (e.g. printing to a terminal, writing/reading a file, etc...), memory functions (allocating/freeing), etc... Note that the C standard library is actually just a specification for a library (same as OpenGL, and some others), it's not actually a library that you can download and use. This is why there are implementations such as the BSD's (I'll call it the BSD libc, for convenience), GNU's (which, by the way, is included by default in ubuntu, under the name of `libc`), or, in this case, Bionic. But as wikipedia said, Bionic is based off of the BSD libc, so it's not an original implementation. Now about the actual implementation, I'm not sure what's the difference between Bionic and the BSD libc, but I would think it has something to do with compatability of their devices, or something along the likes of that (since one of the reasons why the C standard library is just a specification is that how the functions work differ from OS to OS).

[libhybris](https://github.com/stskeeps/libhybris) is an extension, if you want, to bionic that acts like `libdl` (source: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE5Mjk). If you're wondering what `libdl` is, it's a library that allows applications to dynamically load other libraries into their applications. This is extremely useful (if not impossible to do without) for plugins and such.

Hope this clarifies!